# Using Haskell map when functions needs an intermediate result

Tags: haskell

I'm working thorough a Haskell text and have come across a question about making change. I'm given an ordered list of (denomonation, numCoins) tuples along with an amount and need to return a list of how many of each coin was used to make change. I have the following code that solves the problem:

```
useCoins :: (Int,Int) -> Int -> Int
useCoins (denomination, numCoins) target = min numCoins (target `div` denomination)

makeChange :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> [Int]
makeChange [] target = []
makeChange ((denomination, numCoins):xs) target = 
  let
     coinsUsed = useCoins (denomination, numCoins) target
  in coinsUsed : makeChange xs (target - (coinsUsed * denomination))
```

The problem is that this is in a chapter on higher-order functions and I'm having a hard time coming up with a way to use map as the target value is changing as it drops through the list. I'd love any help.

Thanks.

-mh

Comment: As a general note, try to avoid using 'let' and 'in' statements within functions. It's a very 'OOP-like', instead try to think about structuring functions using recursion, for example, or with where clauses. I'd also suggest that you take your function type statements to the highest abstraction, so using '(Integral a) =>' here would be useful'

Comment: @BabraCunningham `let` vs `where` is mostly a matter of style and personal preference. Neither is OOP-like, in my view. Further, `let` is usable in subexpressions, while `where` is not. For what it is worth, I tend to use `where` when the function body fits a line, and `let` otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

`map` is the wrong function to use, because as you note it only works for situations where each element can be handled independently, not when elements depend on each other.

However, `makeChange` is a function that is implementable with a fold. Specifically, your implementation incorporates all the feature of a left fold, but done by hand; you can instead implement your function in terms of `foldl'`.